# How to find out which package version is loaded in R?

Tags: r, package, version

I am in a process of figuring out how to use my university cluster. It has 2 versions of R installed. System wide R 2.11 (Debian 6.0) and R 2.14.2 in non-standard location.

I am trying to use MPI together with snow. The code I am trying to run is the following

```
library(snow)
library(Rmpi)
cl <- makeMPIcluster(mpi.universe.size()-1)
stopCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

It works without the problems on R 2.11. (I launch the script with `mpirun -H localhost,n1,n2,n3,n4 -n 1 R --slave -f code.R`). Now when I try to do it with R 2.14.2, I get the following message:

```
Error: This is R 2.11.1, package 'snow' needs >= 2.12.1
In addition: Warning message:
```

So it seems that R loads the package snow version compiled for R 2.11. I've installed snow under R 2.14 into my home folder and I added the following lines to my code:

```
.libPaths("/soft/R/lib/R/library")
.libPaths("~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.11")
print(.libPaths())
print(sessionInfo())
print(version)
```

And the output before the error confirms that I am indeed running R 2.14.2 and my R packages folder is first in search path. But I still get the error.

So my question is how do I determine which version of package is loaded in R? I can see with  `installed.packages` all the packages which are installed, so maybe there is some function which lists similar information for loaded packages?

Comment: did you find a good solution for this issue? In my experience and as the R help indicates, both sessionInfo and packageVersion return the _the current version installed at the location the package was loaded from: it can be wrong if another process has been changing packages during the session._

Answer (score 741, accepted):

You can use `sessionInfo()` to accomplish that.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     grid      methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.0  reshape2_1.2.1 plyr_1.7.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       MASS_7.3-18        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3       
 [7] proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 scales_0.2.0       stringr_0.6       
>
```

However, as per comments and the answer below, there are better options

```
> packageVersion("snow")
```

[1] ‘0.3.9’

Or:

```
"Rmpi" %in% loadedNamespaces()
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was to output sessionInfo before the package loading. In the end it turned out that the correct version of package was loaded, but R still complained about the old version. Installed my own local version of R and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: TMI! `packageVersion()` is much better in most cases

Comment: I would not advise to use `sessionInfo`. See the Note of ?sessionInfo: _"The information on ‘loaded’ packages and namespaces is the current version installed at the location the package was loaded from: it can be wrong if another process has been changing packages during the session."_
So: if you want to know wether the package is loaded or not, better use `"Rmpi" %in% loadedNamespaces()` ; if you want to know which version is installed in a specific location, better use `packageVersion(lib.loc = ...)`

Comment: See Gábor's answer below for an answer that returns the version of a **currently loaded package** (which may be different from the on-disk version): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369263/946850

Answer (score 363):

You can use [`utils::packageVersion`](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/packageDescription.html) to see what version of a package is installed:

```
> packageVersion("snow")
[1] ‘0.3.9’
```

[Note that](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/packageDescription.html#heading-3)

> A package will not be ‘found’ unless it has a `DESCRIPTION` file which contains a valid `Version` field. Different warnings are given when no package directory is found and when there is a suitable directory but no valid `DESCRIPTION` file.

Although it sounds like you want to see what version of R you are running, in which case [@Justin's `sessionInfo` suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11103209/7196903) is the way to go.

Comment: This answer clearly wins for me as you can use it to write neat conditions. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 45):

Technically speaking, all of the answers at this time are wrong. `packageVersion` does not return the version of the loaded package. It goes to the disk, and fetches the package version from there.

This will not make a difference in most cases, but sometimes it does. As far as I can tell, the only way to get the version of a *loaded* package is the rather hackish:

```
asNamespace(pkg)$`.__NAMESPACE__.`$spec[["version"]]
```

where `pkg` is the package name.

EDIT: I am not sure when this function was added, but you can also use `getNamespaceVersion`, this is cleaner:

```
getNamespaceVersion(pkg)
```

Comment: `\`:::\`(pkg, .__NAMESPACE__.)$spec[["version"]]` is a synonym of the `asNamespace()` method of getting the package version.

Comment: This answer is so important. `packageVersion()` only shows you the top result in `installed.packages()` but if you have multiple version of the same package, and you load one specifically, it won't give you the right answer.

Comment: Per https://hughjonesd.shinyapps.io/rcheology/ it's been available since available as early as R 1.7.0.

Comment: It seems that `packageVersion` does return the version of the loaded package by default. The docs for the `lib.loc` argument read: "The default value of `NULL` corresponds to all libraries currently known. If the default is used, the _loaded packages_ and namespaces are searched before the libraries." 
Emphasis mine.

Comment: @dpprdan this is new and was not the case when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Another thing to note is that `getNamespaceVersion()` returns a character, not a `package_version()` object.

Answer (score 25):

To check the version of R execute : `R --version`

Or after you are in the R shell print the contents of `version$version.string`

**EDIT**

To check the version of installed packages do the following.

After loading the library, you can execute `sessionInfo ()`

But to know the list of all installed packages:

```
packinfo <- installed.packages(fields = c("Package", "Version"))
packinfo[,c("Package", "Version")]
```

OR to extract a specific library version, once you have extracted the information using the `installed.package` function as above just use the name of the package in the first dimension of the matrix.

```
packinfo["RANN",c("Package", "Version")]
packinfo["graphics",c("Package", "Version")]
```

The above will print the versions of the RANN library and the graphics library.

Comment: The question was about package version, not R version. And if look at my code, I use `version`.

Comment: `packinfo[,  "Version", drop=F]` gives even more *pretty* result (package name is not duplicated).

Answer (score 21):

You can try something like this:

1. `package_version(R.version)`
2. `getRversion()`

Answer (score 16):

**GUI solution:**

If you are using RStudio then you can check the package version in the `Packages` pane.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use the R method `packageDescription` to get the installed package description and for version just use `$Version` as:

```
packageDescription("AppliedPredictiveModeling")$Version
[1] "1.1-6"
```

Comment: There's a convenience function `utils::packageVersion()` that directly parses the `Version` field, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11103291/7196903

Answer (score 5):

Based on the previous answers, here is a simple alternative way of printing the R-version, followed by the name and version of each package loaded in the namespace. It works in the Jupyter notebook, where I had troubles running `sessionInfo()` and `R --version`.

```
print(paste("R", getRversion()))
print("-------------")
for (package_name in sort(loadedNamespaces())) {
    print(paste(package_name, packageVersion(package_name)))
}
```

Out:

```
[1] "R 3.2.2"
[1] "-------------"
[1] "AnnotationDbi 1.32.2"
[1] "Biobase 2.30.0"
[1] "BiocGenerics 0.16.1"
[1] "BiocParallel 1.4.3"
[1] "DBI 0.3.1"
[1] "DESeq2 1.10.0"
[1] "Formula 1.2.1"
[1] "GenomeInfoDb 1.6.1"
[1] "GenomicRanges 1.22.3"
[1] "Hmisc 3.17.0"
[1] "IRanges 2.4.6"
[1] "IRdisplay 0.3"
[1] "IRkernel 0.5"
```

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but not among the answers is my favorite command to get a quick and short overview of all loaded packages:

```
(.packages())
```

To see which version is installed of all loaded packages, just use the above command to subset `installed.packages()`.

```
installed.packages()[(.packages()),3]
```

By changing the column number (3 for package version) you can get any other information stored in `installed.packages()` in an easy-to-read matrix. Below is an example for version number and dependency:

```
installed.packages()[(.packages()),c(3,5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Search() can give a more simplified list of the attached packages in a session (i.e., without the detailed info given by sessionInfo())

search {base}- R Documentation
Description: Gives a list of attached packages. [Search()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/search.html)

```
search()
#[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:Rfacebook" "package:httpuv"   
#"package:rjson"    
#[5] "package:httr"      "package:bindrcpp"  "package:forcats"   # 
#"package:stringr"  
#[9] "package:dplyr"     "package:purrr"     "package:readr"     
#"package:tidyr"    
#[13] "package:tibble"    "package:ggplot2"   "package:tidyverse" 
#"tools:rstudio"    
#[17] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" 
#"package:utils"    
#[21] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         
#"package:base"
```

Comment: Yes, but sessionInfo gives the version number too. In my case the latter is usually more important.

Answer (score 2):

To add on @GSee's answer, note that the returned value of `utils::packageVersion()` is not a `character` and that you can perfectly use it to write conditions:

```r
packageVersion("dplyr")
#> [1] '1.0.7'
packageVersion("dplyr")>1
#> [1] TRUE
packageVersion("dplyr")>'1.0'
#> [1] TRUE
packageVersion("dplyr")>'1.1'
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to obtain the version of R packages installed in the system:

```
installed.packages(fields = c ("Package", "Version"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `help(package="my_package")` and look at the version shown.

This assumes there are no other package versions in the same `.libPaths`.