# How to write a "reader-friendly" sessionInfo() to text file

Tags: r

I would like to save the output of "sessionInfo()" to a text file. Using "write()" failed because "list() cannot be handled by 'cat()'". I then tried "save()" with ascii = T but the resulting file is not really helpful.

I would like to have an output [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11103209/2369943) in a text file. Any easy, straightforward way to do this?

Comment: I was looking for an option that can be included in an R markdown file (Rmd) and prints nicely to PDF/HTML. With my approach for this, I ended up providing an answer to a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65630773/10451245).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Capture the screen output into a character vector and use `writeLines`.

```
writeLines(capture.output(sessionInfo()), "sessionInfo.txt")
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks -- I did not now the capture.output() function.

Answer (score 15):

```
‘sink’ diverts R output to a connection.
```

```
sink("sessionInfo.txt")
sessionInfo()
sink()
```

sessionInfo.txt:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.0.2 tools_3.0.2
```

Answer (score 9):

You might want to use `session_info()` from the `devtools` package. In that case you use `sink()` as explained in one of the answers here or you can use the following to have the headers and make it more self-explanatory (since `print(session_info())` use `message()` for displaying the header):

```r
library("devtools")
library("knitr")

my_session_info <- devtools::session_info()

writeLines(text = {
    paste(sep = "\n", collapse = "",
          paste0(rep("-", 80), collapse = ""),
          paste(paste0(rep("-", 32), collapse = ""),
                "R environment",
                paste0(rep("-", 33), collapse = "")),
          paste0(rep("-", 80), collapse = ""),
          paste(knitr::kable(t(data.frame(my_session_info$platform)), col.names = "value"), collapse = "\n"),
          paste0(rep(" ", 80), collapse = ""),      # some separator
          paste0(rep(" ", 80), collapse = ""),      # some separator
          paste0(rep("-", 80), collapse = ""),
          paste(paste0(rep("-", 35), collapse = ""),
                "packages",
                paste0(rep("-", 35), collapse = "")),
          paste0(rep("-", 80), collapse = ""),
          paste(knitr::kable(my_session_info$packages), collapse = "\n")
    )
}, con = "session_info.txt")
```

[ p.s Remember to `library(devtools)` ]

Comment: +1 for `devtools::session_info`. It's much easier to read, since it's alphabetized. It also has nice extras like the commit hash for packages installed from github or bitbucket.

Answer (score 5):

As previously mentioned, you can use `devtools::session_info()` to get an object that is easier to deal with. I then use `yaml::write_yaml()` (alternatively `jsonlite::write_json()`) to write the object into a machine readable *and* human readable version. For example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(devtools)
library(yaml)

session_info() %>%
    write_yaml("./path/to/file.yaml")
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like we don't need writeLines() as we can directly specify the output file to capture.output() function.

```
sessionInfo() %>% capture.output(file="session_info.txt")
```