# Installing, Loading Packages & Verifying these actions. Path, Lib, Dependencies, etc

Tags: r, path, package, installation, load

This is one of the more comprehensive threads and discussions on these topics I have located to date.

[How to find out which package version is loaded in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103189/how-to-find-out-which-package-version-is-loaded-in-r)

Nonetheless, I am finding this has not provided me with sufficient information to ensure I have installed and loaded the two packages I must have before I can begin to expect R to function properly.  These packages are: Rserve (1.8-0) and MASS (7.3-45).

It seems answers to these topics can be application dependent or, perhaps purpose driven is a better phrase to use.  Unfortunately, the R documentation will confuse you so, I thought it best to solicit the input of more experienced users.

I am working on a personal laptop with R 3.5.1 and Win7 Pro.  It is clear from the r documentation that Windows is not the best or preferred environment for R.

despite a lot of work something remains missing and I have been unable to identify what it is.

Comment: Can you make your question(s) a bit more explicit?

Comment: Windows is really not a great environment for anything but spreading malware, enabling ransomware & costing companies millions of $ due to cyberattacks. The R Core team just isn't shy about noting how horrible it is. Also, how is `grep("^(MASS|Rserve)$", installed.packages()[,1], value=TRUE)` not straightforward and what you want?